# Plot modify datapoints in barchart (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting a barchart using ggplot2.

```
D0=c(1,2,3)
D1=c(5,6,7)
D2=c(9,10,11)
average_D0=mean(D0)
average_D1=mean(D1)
average_D2=mean(D2)
df = data.frame(dose=c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"),
                len=c(average_D0, average_D1, average_D2))            
p = ggplot(data=df, aes(x=dose, y=len)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Goal: plotting data points +1 on the plot.

ex. for D0 column, I want to plot the data points (2,3,4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following?:

```
D0=c(1,2,3)
D1=c(5,6,7)
D2=c(9,10,11)

df <- cbind(D0, D1, D2)
df <- reshape2::melt(df)

ggplot(df) +
  stat_summary(aes(Var2, value), fun.y = mean, geom = "col") +
  geom_point(aes(Var2, value + 1))
```

[image]